# If using outlook to connect to exchange, how to recover contact groups?

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2010, microsoft-office-365

So recently we had to move to another exchange server and migrated all data over. Some PC's running outlook had to have their account in outlook recreated (By going into Account settings and removing the account and creating the account), while others needed to have the profile removed from the control panel >> Mail settings.

The issue is, some of the users were using contact groups they created within outlook to mass email clients. However, upon recreating the user's outlook accounts these group contacts no longer appear. Looks like instead of saving to the exchange server, it was being saved locally. They are using Outlook 2010

The old/original .ost files still exist. The accounts were just removed within outlook but no files have been deleted.

I am trying to figure out the following things:

1. Is there a way to recover the contact groups?
2. Is there a way to make the contacts groups created locally by the end user, save to the server?
3. Where does the data for the contact groups save to?

Thank you.

Comment: What client OS are you using?  Also, I'm afraid that the only contact group I have is actually replicated to the server (Outlook 2010, Exchange 2007).  Have you tried mounting the .ost as external storage and seeing if it's there (perhaps renaming it to .pst first)?

Comment: The OS is win7 pro. Can you elaborate on what you mean by mounting the .ost as external storage? My outlook/exchange experience is a bit limited.

Comment: I could have sworn I'd mounted .ost files before, but I must have been mistaken.  :(  There are third party conversion utilities, but...

Comment: Thank you for the replies. One would think microsoft could easily create a program to convert from one of their proprietary file formats into another one of their formats lol. I guess my hopes were too high, I only have a few mailboxes but the cost of the 3rd party tools doesn't justify the cost.